# How to find examples of best cases for sorting algorithms?

Tags: data-structures, asymptotics, sorting

I am asked to give a table of 8 elements that are to be sorted by the following algorithms and to produce their best cases.
1) Selection sort
2) Bubble sort
3) Insertion sort
4) Fusion sort

If I give an already sorted table ex: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} shouldn't it already be the best case for all of them? If I can be considered a best case for each?

Comment: "If I can be considered a best case for each?" What do you mean by that sentence? Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Bubble sort can "stop early" should the array already be sorted. Other algorithms have their own advantages or applications, but none of the algorithms mentioned in your question - other than bubble sort - can "stop early".

Therefore for any input Insertion & Selection runtime will be $\Omega (n^2) $, and Mergesort $\Omega(nlog(n))$, so the order of elements doesn't matter at all.

$\bullet $ If you perform bubble sort on an already sorted array, the algorithm can stop when not performing any swaps, and run at $O(n)$

$\bullet $ Merge sort (to which you refer as 'fusion sort' from some reason) is the only algorithm that requires $O(nlog(n))$ rather than $O(n^2)$

$\bullet $ Insertion sort is useful when receiving the array online (one element at a time) and maintaining it sorted. Its noteworthy that since you maintain a sorted array, new elements can be inserted via binary search, which make the insertion sort perform $O(nlog(n))$ comparisons, but still cost $O(n^2)$ due to moving elements.

$\bullet $ Selection sort is very easy to implement and intuitive to explain

Comment: By the way, you can use `\log` to denote $\log$ such as in $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: It may not be a bad idea to add a linear check if the array is sorted in any step (which can make both insertion and selection also linear in best case), but not sure OP meant modified algorithms. I did not think of a binsearch insertion, that is an insteresting point and i will edit it in. Thanks.

Comment: An insertion algorithm that compares the last element in the result array with the new element will run $O(n)$ on $1,2,3,\cdots,n$. (Of course, binary search for insertion is a very interesting variation.) Even if "new elements can be inserted via binary search", that does not make it run in $O(n\log n)$. Binary search reduces the number of comparisons; however, the steps that are needed for the actual insertion take $\Theta(n^2)$ in average.

Comment: You're right. edited it. No, i didn't implement any variation of insertion sort

Comment: Upvoted, although this answer still misses some finer (or pedantic) details.